# How do I join 2 columns of a Pandas Data Frame by a comma?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to join 2 columns of a Pandas Data Frame with a comma, i.e.: "abc" in column 1 joins with "123" in column 2 to become "abc, 123".

For example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'IDx': ['a','b',np.nan,'C'], 'IDy':['1','','2','D']})
>>> df
   IDx  IDy
0    a    1
1    b     
2  NaN    2
3    C    D
```

The following do not work:

```
>>> ', '.join([df['IDx'],df['IDy']])
>>> df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join([x['IDx'],x['IDy']]))
```

This is the desired result:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['a, 1', 'b', '2', 'C, D']})
>>> df
     ID
0  a, 1
1     b
2     2
3  C, D
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to empty `string`, [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) columns to `string` and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['ID'] = df[['IDx', 'IDy']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.fillna('').map(str)), axis=1)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.strip(',')
print df
   IDx IDy   ID
0    a   1  a,1
1    b        b
2  NaN   2    2
3    C   D  C,D
```

Or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to empty string and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `string` and [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['IDx'].fillna('').astype(str) + ',' + df['IDy'].fillna('').astype(str)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.strip(',')
print df
   IDx IDy   ID
0    a   1  a,1
1    b        b
2  NaN   2    2
3    C   D  C,D
```

EDIT: If `dtype` of your columns is `string`, you can omit `map` or `astype`:

```
df['ID'] = df[['IDx', 'IDy']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.fillna('')), axis=1)
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.strip(',')
```

Or:

```
df['ID'] = df['IDx'].fillna('') + ',' + df['IDy'].fillna('')
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.strip(',')
print df
```